# how to target padding bottom with .replace mthod

Tags: jquery, replace

New to jQuery and I'm trying to modify this script:

```
$(function(){
positionFooter(); 
function positionFooter(){
    var padding_top = $(".footer").css("padding-top").replace("px", "");
    var page_height = $(document.body).height() - padding_top;
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var difference = window_height - page_height;
    if (difference < 0) 
        difference = 0;

    $(".footer").css({
        padding: difference + "px 0 0 0"
    })
}

$(window)
    .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

It works fine; I just would like to add padding-bottom to the body container instead of padding-top to the footer as there is a gap between the body bg and the footer currently.

The html is:

```
<div class="sys_main_content container">
    <section>
</div>
<footer class="footer">
```

I want to add padding bottom to the section part.  this didn;t work:

```
$(function(){
positionFooter(); 
function positionFooter(){
    var padding_top = $("section").css("padding-bottom").replace("px", "");
    var page_height = $(document.body).height() - padding_top;
    var window_height = $(window).height();
    var difference = window_height - page_height;
    if (difference < 0) 
        difference = 0;

    $("section").css({
        padding: difference + "0 0 px 0"
    })
}

$(window)
    .resize(positionFooter)
});
```

Though it is close...i can see the style inserted, it's just empty.

many thanks in advance.

Comment: The padding is obviously set in CSS, you should first change there and then modify the script accordingly... and it'll help if you share the css as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of these

```
$("section").css({
    padding: "0 0 " + difference + "px 0"
})
```

or

```
$("section").css({
    "padding-bottom": difference + "px"
})
```

Comment: Perfect.  This worked...i just forgot about concatenating variables and strings.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
padding: "0 0 "+ difference + "px 0"
```

writing `padding` basically sets `top right bottom left` . This is the **order**.

Comment: yea - I just forgot about concatenating (the positioning).  Thanks for the quick reply.